# ASP.net Core2 how to add extra data to a post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to send some extra data in my form and read it controller side.

My form is a basic form created with Html.BeginForm and has a couple of Html.Textboxes in it that correspond to columns in the model. The model passed into the controller has the correct information so far, but I'm unsure how to send information not on the model, and how to pick it up on the controller.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some code? I mean this sounds like you could use some kind of `hidden` inputs in your view. But to be sure please share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how to pass extra data from a form and consume it in the controller:

Your controller will accept your model + the extra data. If you have multiple parameters you can add them to the method signature.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MyMethod(MyData myData, string extra)
    {
    }
```

In your form you can pass the extra data with the asp-route-* attribute:

```
@model MyData

<form asp-action="MyMethod" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-extra="myExtraData">
    <input asp-for="Name"/>
    <input asp-for="Age" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And your model class would look like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am mostly interested on how the extra parameters are picked up on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can post any input data as form input. I used hidden input.

**model**

```
public class MyModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyModelPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        model field : @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) <br />
        custom field(can be any input) : <input type="hidden" name="extraParam" value="extra value" >
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
}
```

**controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MyModelPost(MyModel model,string extraParam){
        Debug.WriteLine($"model param {model.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"extra param {extraParam}");
        return View();
        //out put:
        // model param adsfs
        // extra param extra value

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would the order of the parameters after MyModel be in the order top to bottom they appear in the view?

Comment: should be in form element, order is not important.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to link by name of element to name of the parameter.
I thought only the types of the parameters would be visible outside of the method, not the name.

Anyways, I got it to work, Thanks!